# Необходимость в постановке двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Задание на патриотизм: пойти, бить себя в грудь кулаком, кричать "Я россиянин!"

Корректен ли в самом начале предложения предлог "на" и обязательна ли постановка двоеточия перед "Я россиянин!" - является ли это высказывание прямой речью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Задание на "патриотизм": пойти, бить себя в грудь кулаком, кричать "Я россиянин!".**

**1.** В толково-словообразовательном словаре Ефремовой:
**задание**, ср.
1) Возложенная на кого-либо задача, поручение.
2) Замысел, цель, задача.
3) То, что задано; **упражнение**, урок, предложенные ученикам для выполнения.

Задание на логику, задание на сообразительность, задание на патриотизм — думаю, что так можно говорить. Вот только в данном контексте патриотизмом и "не пахнет", потому что вопли и битье себя в грудь не есть характеристики патриотизма. Слово необходимо заключить в кавычки.

*Патриотизм — преданность и любовь к своему отечеству, к своему народу и готовность к любым жертвам и подвигам во имя интересов своей Родины*.

**2.** Можно обойтись без двоеточия (то есть оформления прямой речи), но тогда в конце повествовательного предложения необходима точка.

Answer (score 0):

*Грамматически* предлог подходит, но выражение "задание на патриотизм" стилистически неестественно. Более осмысленные словосочетания: *тест/проверка на патриотизм, задание на демонстрацию своего патриотизма, задание на развитие в себе задатков патриотизма*. Проблема в том, что сам "патриотизм" (в отличие от напр. "проявлений патриотизма") несоизмерим с "заданием" по временным рамкам существования. Необходимость в двоеточии зависит от того, насколько буквально "задают" выкрикиваемое.